# ASP.NET Non existent URL files on server, use Rewrite?

Tags: url-rewriting

How do you get filenotonserver.html to show up in a browser? and not 404 error. How can I do a URL rewrite to match .html to default2.aspx, or vice versa??

Do this make any sense? I am newbie on URL rewrite for sure...

k, been looking around:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="SpecificRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^page$" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="/page.html" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

In the "match url" trying to match .html and action type would be default.aspx?p=whatevetmatched.html

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

ok so I got it:

```
 <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect">
                <match url="(.*)\.html$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="default2.aspx?p={R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

And on the default2.aspx reads the request("p") which has the "matched" html name and I then look it up in the database to display the data for that matched html "page"